# Sending Files and Metadata in Jersey Rest Service

Tags: rest, jersey

I need to create a ReST service using Jersey 2.0. I need to send multiple documents and metadata to the client.
What is the best approach do to the achieve this.

I was able to send a MultiPart response from the server , but not sure how to read this from the client code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a document called "document1" which you want to get via your client.
In your REST-API your unique identifier for the document (the resource) could be:

http://example.com/restapi/documents/document1

As you want to READ data you do a HTTP-GET Request to that uri. 
And here comes the important part for you: A resource can have multiple representations - meta data and binary data in your case.

So the client has to tell the server which representation type to get (content negotiation). This information can be set in the ACCEPT Header of the client request for instance.
You can use the content type "application/json" as a representation for the meta data.

Unfortunately you didn't tell us what kind of binary data you want to send.
If they are PDFs the content type would be "application/pdf" for instance. If the binary data doesn't have a specific type you can use "application/octet-stream".

Of course there is work to be done on the server side too. Here an example:

```
@Path("/documents/{documentname}")
public class docResource {

    @GET @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getDocumentMetaData(@PathParam("documentname") String docName) {
        // Create a Response containing a json
    }
    @GET @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response getDocumentBinaryData(@PathParam("documentname") String docName) {
        // Create a response containing the binary data
    }

    ...
}
```

Jersey will check the accept header of the client and will run the appropriate method.
Also see: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

If you are using jersey with jackson you can also easily marshal a POJO to JSON and visa versa:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

If you are not sure what to do in the "getDocumentBinaryData"-Method - checkout this simple example from mkyong:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-excel-file-from-jax-rs/

Comment: Can the web service return of of document1 and document2 in one request/response. How can we do that. Any pointer wiil be great help.